# Difference between this.show and this.show() function calling?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
        $('html').addClass('js');
        var contactForm = {
            init: function(){
                $('<button></button>',{
                    text: 'contact me'
                }).appendTo('article')
                **.on('click', this.show);**
            }, 

            show: function(){
                console.log('show is clicked');
            }
        }

        contactForm.init();
    });
```

In the onClick call, why does the `.on('click', this.show());` gets executed immediately when the dom is loaded and later get only happens on the click of the button.

Comment: Why does executing a function execute the function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The brackets at the end mean that the preceding function should be invoked immediately. Without the brackets, it becomes a reference to the function.

Therefore `on('click', this.show());` will mean that the `show` function is invoked on load when the `click` handler is set, and it's return value is set to the event handler.

Where as `on('click', this.show);` gives the click handler the reference to the `show` function, which will be called when the `click` event happens.

Best practice is to *only* pass the reference of a function to an event handler - ie. the latter example.

Comment: `and then also when the click event occurs` I'm not sure that part is correct.

Comment: on('click, this.show()) only executes once on the dom loading... and after that the click event does trigger.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum you're correct, I edited the wrong paragraph.

Answer (score 3):

'on()' is a function that (in this case) takes two arguments.

`this.show` passes a reference to the function named `show`.

`this.show()` invokes the function and passes the return value.